# How to disable on screen keyboard on logon?

Tags: windows-vista, login, tablet

Yesterday I installed an old Wacom USB tablet just for fun, to see if it worked with Vista, and it did, since I've found a working driver.

The only thing annoying me is that now my laptop has been setup as a tablet, and an on-screen-keyboard is shown at the logon.

Not really an issue, but since I've googled around and found no answer apart from [disabling all the tablet features entirely](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/remove-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-the-vista-login-screen/) I was wondering if there was a registry hack-around to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was actually in the comments of [the link I posted in my question](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/remove-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-the-vista-login-screen/#comment-71477)

> Control Panel > Type “Device Manager” in search contents box > Human Interface devices > Wacom HID > Disable Wacom Virtual HID driver.
>
> You’ll still keep pressure-sensitivity in applications with your tablet, but this got rid of my on-screen keyboard completely after I disabled the process.

I'm still investigating on any side-effect. By the way this seemed to do the trick, and it can be reverted back!

Answer (score 7):

control panel > ease of access > use the computer without a mouse or
keyboard > clear 'onscreen keyboard'

Comment: unfortunately that is already unchecked. but still, thank you

Comment: This was already set for me too. I found that toggling the setting fixed the issue. Toggle it **on**, then **off** again.

Answer (score 2):

I [found something on a forum](http://itsvista.com/2007/06/itsvista-tip-60-hide-a-persistant-on-screen-keyboard-in-vista/) that seems your logical options:

> I wanted to share another workaround I
> found (out of desperation) after
> installing my Wacom Tablet and dealing
> with the persistent appearance of the
> on-screen keyboard.
>
> I went to:
>
> - Start
> - Windows Help & Support
> - System Info
> - Software
> - Installed Programs
> - View enabled Windows features
> - Tablet PC Optional Components and I unchecked that box.
>
> Since I don’t have a Tablet PC and
> only have an installed tablet, I
> thought there might be conflicting
> drivers.
>
> When I rebooted, the on-screen
> keyboard at logon had been eliminated.
> My Wacom tablet works great and the
> on-screen keyboard has disappeared.
> This action doesn’t appear to have
> disabled anything I use on a regular
> basis, and everything seems to be
> working fine. The solution may not
> work for anyone else, but it has for
> me.

Or [try these options:](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/96297-anyone-know-how-turn-off-screen-keyboard.html)

> Here are a few things to check ...
>
> First, go to Control Panel, Ease of
> Access. Then click on the link "Use
> the computer without a mouse or
> keyboard". Make sure the checkbox
> marked "Use On screen keyboard" is
> UNchecked (ie, clear).
>
> That's your first and most important
> place to check. After that, it gets a
> bit more obscure. The On Screen
> Keyboard program is "osk.exe".
> Presumably something is causing
> osk.exe to be run, every time you log
> in.
>
> In the Start menu, look in the Startup
> folder. Make sure there are no
> shortcuts there pointing towards
> osk.exe. If there are, move the
> shortcut to another location, or just
> delete it.
>
> Next, run the command "msconfig". If
> prompted for admin credentials, enter
> them. Then, look under the Startup
> tab. Look for any entries which appear
> to run osk.exe. If you see one,
> uncheck teh entry, and then press
> Apply.
>
> Next, run Regedit. If prompted for
> credentials, enter your own, current
> username and password. Then navigate
> to the registry key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>
> If you see a value under there which
> runs osk.exe, delete that value.
>
> If you've looked at Ease of Access,
> the Startup folder, the MSConfig
> startups, and the HKEY Current User
> Run key, and you don't find the
> osk.exe Onscreen keyboard anywhere in
> any of them, then ... sorry, I really
> don't know. Maybe someone else will
> know. Or else, learn to enjoy having
> an On screen keyboard! :-)

Comment: unfortunately the first solution is what I wanted to avoid (provided link); as for the second, the osk.exe is a user mode process which is started *after* the logon, so it's not related

but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm four years late...but here is the likely culprit:

> regedit.exe ->
>   local machine ->
>   software ->
>   microsoft ->
>   windows nt ->
>   winlogon (winlogin?) ->
>   system=osk.exe

Delete the system entry.

Comment: Your post is hard to read. Could you use `->` separators to clarify the registry path?

Answer (score 0):

For me, using a Cintiq 13HD, simply go to Control Panel > Tablet PC Settings > Other (tab) > Go to input panel settings - Uncheck everything on the first tab.