# (Windows 10) On screen keyboard appears at login screen after installing tablet driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, on-screen-keyboard, graphics-tablet

After installing Huion Tablet driver (v14.8.166.1482_HID), I put my computer into sleep mode. When I turned the computer back on, on logonUI appears on-screen keyboard. This happens only when the graphic tablet unplugged.

- Ease of access & windows settings osk disabled. Windows tablet mode disabled. [[1]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/the-on-screen-keyboard-keeps-opening-in-login/540ff38d-389c-4f1e-b0dd-6deebde9151f) [[2]](https://www.howtogeek.com/269669/how-to-stop-windows-10s-touch-keyboard-from-popping-up-at-login/#:%7E:text=Disable%20the%20Touch%20Keyboard%20in%20Ease%20of%20Access&text=Press%20Enter%20when%20the%20Ease,it%E2%80%93just%20for%20good%20measure.) [[3]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop-winpc/how-to-stop-on-screen-keyboard-from-popping-up/509cfa40-054b-4a1f-a0c3-9eb25a0bf5df)
- [I can't find service "Touch keyboard and handwriting panel" in services.msc](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-touch/disable-virtual-keyboard-on-startup/805cab5d-9769-44f5-affe-1edf1ad1ff39?auth=1)
- [Registry key "ShowTabletKeyboard" are 0](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/on-screen-keyboard-appears-at-login-screen-after/08d91552-2b67-4ce6-ac87-b7c8089718e8?auth=1)
- [Disabling or uninstalling HID driver will lead to incorrect tablet working](https://superuser.com/a/48422/1218747)

System Configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- version 20H2
- reinstalled 03.1.2021
- build 19042.685

Comment: Is Windows in tablet mode?

Comment: no, it isn't...

Answer (score 0):

try installing the latest version of the driver, then launch the driver, then go to settings, general, and click on administrative privilege's, this solved this problem for me. I'm using Huion Hs610 by the way, but huion driver is pretty similar across most of their pen tablets
[huion driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgaWU.png)

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRvy3.png)

[enable administrative privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsC9x.png)